# Google Apps Script Un/Marshal from XSD Mappings?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, xsd

I have Javascript mappings I generated using Jsonix from a tree of XSD files. How do I use the mappings Javascript file in Google Apps Script to marshal Javascript objects to XML (for submission to a REST API that the XSD defines) and unmarshal the XML response back into Javascript objects? Or is there a different way than Jsonix to generate mappings I can use in GAS? Thanks for your insights.

Jsonix works inside Node.js, but the Jsonix.js script when converted to a GAS library resource (Jsonix.gs) and called by the GAS environment doesn't supply some libraries the Jsonix factory wrapper function. XMLDOM, XMLHttpRequest and fs arguments all arrive valued as undefined. So I can't use Jsonix to marshal/unmarshal. I use Jsonix at the commandline for the onetime generation of the mappings Javascript from the XSD files.

Comment: Hi. I'm looking at older questions, like yours, that don't have any comments or answers. Did you resolve your "problem", or are you still looking for help?

Comment: No thanks, I worked it out by embedding Jsonix in a GAS library and tweaking it until it worked.